# Failed to read a .csv file. Getting FileNotFoundException error after switching from JOptionPane to console I/O

Tags: java, csv, exception, console, filereader

Here are two versions of the same method. the first one uses JOptionPane and the second one uses console. They are supposed to take a file path (string) from  user input to find the file and read it.

The first method works just fine but the second method which uses console gave me a FileNotFoundException error. Why doesn't the second one work if they both are almost identical?

//USING JOptionPane
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void addFromFile() {

```
    String[] option1 = { "Go back to Main Manu", "Continue" };

    int choice4 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "Warning: this method will delete existing data before it add file data", "Monster Database",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, option1, null);

    if (choice4 == 0)
        monitor();

    if (choice4 == 1) {

        monsterAttackList.clear();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filePath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a filepath");

        File inFile = new File(filePath);

        try {
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inFile);

            String line;
            String[] part;
            int attackID;
            String monster;
            String date;
            String location;
            String reporter;

            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = fileReader.nextLine();
                part = line.split(",");
                attackID = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
                monster = part[1];
                date = part[2];
                location = part[3];
                reporter = part[4];

                monsterAttackList.add(new MonsterAttack(attackID, monster, date, location, reporter));
            }

            fileReader.close(); // Close to unlock.
            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "filepath is not valid");
            System.err.println(e);

        }
    }

}
```

// USING SCANNER
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public void addFromFile() {

    System.out.println("Warning: this method will delete existing data before it add file data");
    System.out.println("\n1. Go back to Main Manu" + "\n2. Continue \n");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice4 = input.nextInt();


    if (choice4 == 1)
        monitor();

    if (choice4 == 2) {

        monsterAttackList.clear();

        System.out.println("Enter a filepath");

        String filePath = input.nextLine();

        File inFile = new File(filePath);

        try {
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inFile);

            String line;
            String[] part;
            int attackID;
            String monster;
            String date;
            String location;
            String reporter;

            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = fileReader.nextLine();
                part = line.split(",");
                attackID = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
                monster = part[1];
                date = part[2];
                location = part[3];
                reporter = part[4];

                monsterAttackList.add(new MonsterAttack(attackID, monster, date, location, reporter));
            }

            fileReader.close(); // Close to unlock.
            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("filepath is not valid");
            System.err.println(e);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put a call to `input.nextLine()` after every call to `input.nextInt()`. NextInt does not consume the newline character, only the number.

Comment: Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int choice4 = input.nextInt();

  if (choice4 == 1)
   monitor();

  if (choice4 == 2) {
   input.nextLine(); // free line
   monsterAttackList.clear();

   System.out.println("Enter a filepath");

   String filePath = input.nextLine();

   File inFile = new File(filePath);

Comment: ^how do I make it looks like a code block? Thank you for the help but I still get the same error.